# How to manage property files with Ant?

Tags: ant, properties

I have a program that takes values from a property file(host,port), the path of the property file is currently beign hard coded, but I want to be able to compile and place the property file in the same directory as my compiled classes(in bin/) and when I make a jar and run the program,it should take the values from there automatically, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a "copy" task to copy the property file in your bin directory, inside the same package directory as the java file that needs to read the properties. Then, jar the program, using the "jar" task.

In the java program, you should now be able to read the properties in this way:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("my.properties"));
String host = props.get("hostname");
String port = props.get("port");
```

Comment: ok I got it,so I basically copy file into the same package as the class that uses it, now the problem is that I have hard coded the path to the property file,and it can vary according to who uses it right? How can I get the relative path in java? Everytime I use a relative path it says that the file doesnt exist,when it clearly does.

Comment: If the properties file is in a .jar file, then there is no need for absolute paths. `getResourceAsStream("my.properties")` will load "my.properties" from the root level of the .jar file.